# Merging multiple TextBufferGeometries in a scene

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to change the following code to use TextBufferGeometry instead of TextGeometry as I feel like it may improve the performance in my use case. The code below works for rendering multiple text elements into my scene however when I change..

`let geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(...` to `let geometry = new THREE.TextBufferGeometry(...`

this code no longer renders text into the scene. I'm unsure of what needs changing in order to make use of TextBufferGeometry

```
const materialWhite = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide });

const textArray = [
      { text: `Message 12345`, zDistance: 100 },
      { text: `Message 67890`, zDistance: 200 },
      { text: `Message 13579`, zDistance: 300 },
   ];

var singleFontGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    for (let index = 0; index < textArray.length; index++) {

      loaderFonts.load('./assets/fonts/Oxanium.json', function(font) {

        let geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(`${textArray[index].text}`, {
          font: font,
          size: 20,
          height: 1
        });

        let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialWhite);

        mesh.position.set(100, 100, textArray[index].zDistance);

        singleFontGeometry.mergeMesh(mesh);

      });
    }

var meshFont = new THREE.Mesh(singleFontGeometry, materialWhite);

this.scene.add(meshFont);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above will require three main changes:

1. In the loop, create `THREE.TextBufferGeometry` instances instead of `TextGeometry`.
2. Instead of setting a position on each mesh, bake that transform into the geometry before merging, with `geometry.translate(...)`.
3. Instead of adding geometries to a `THREE.Geometry` instance, create a merged BufferGeometry instance using BufferGeometryUtils. BufferGeometry does not have a `.mergeMesh()` method, and `.merge()` overwrites vertices rather than creating a union, so neither are available here.

Also, but somewhat unrelated to the question, you probably don't want to load the font *inside* your For-loop, to avoid unnecessary requests. With these changes, the code should look something like this:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { BufferGeometryUtils } from 'three/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js';

var mergedGeometry;

// Load the font once.
loaderFonts.load('./assets/fonts/Oxanium.json', function(font) {

  // Then create a *BufferGeometry for each item of text.
  var geometries = textArray.map(function(text) {
    var geometry = new THREE.TextBufferGeometry(text.text, {
      font: font,
      size: 20,
      height: 1
    });

    // Take each item's unique Z offset, and bake it into the geometry.
    geometry.translate(0, 0, text.zDistance);

    return geometry;
  });

  // Merge all text geometries.
  mergedGeometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries( geometries );

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeometry, materialWhite);

  // Put the shared x=100,y=100 offset onto the mesh, so it can be changed later.
  mesh.position.set(100, 100, 0);

  scene.add(mesh);

});
```

^Note that BufferGeometryUtils is not included in the three.js build itself, and must be added to your application separately, like loaders, controls, and other things in the `examples/js*` folder.

Comment: If you have a lot of text, it might also be worth looking at https://github.com/Jam3/three-bmfont-text/, which can give better performance with lower vertex counts. But it behaves somewhat less like a "real object" in the scene, e.g. you can't easily compute a bounding box around the text if I remember correctly.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed response Don, some really handy code style tips! I've had a go with your solution however and I can't seem to get it to work.. when console.loging mergedGeometry I belive the geoms are being merged 
but an error is being thrown down the line ..... THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. undefined ..... tracing back to scene.add(mesh); No text seems to appear in the scene and the triangle count of the scene stays the same as with no text so I'm guessing the mesh & texture add to the scene is failing?

Comment: In the version above, at least, the `mesh` is created just a couple lines above and should be valid... might need to create a demo? Note that I've moved the `scene.add(...)` part inside the font loading callback, compared to the original code.

Comment: My appologies Don, your solution was absolutely correct! I hadn't set my project up correctly to deal with BufferGeomUtils. Christmas break has slowed me right down :) Observations are there are slightly more draw calls however the memory consumption is drastically reduced and everything is running much smoother [This is the end result](https://adamrobinson.dev/). Thanks a bunch & happy new year